# Calling a constructor from a class in the main method?

Tags: java, class, constructor, program-entry-point

I've read some of the other questions, but still couldn't seem to figure out how to get mine to work, any help is appreciated. The code I have so far is given below. I want to be able to call a newPointParameters to create a new class.

```
public class Lab4ex1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("" + 100);

    new newPointParameter(42,24);
}
class Point {
    private double x = 1;
    private double y = 1;

    public double getx() {
        return x;
    }
    public double gety() {
        return y;
    }
    public void changePoint(double newx, double newy) {
        x = newx;
        y = newy;
    }
    public void newPointParameters(double x1, double y1) {
        this.x = x1; 
        this.y = y1;
    }
    public void newPoint() {
        this.x = 10;
        this.y = 10;
    }
    public double distanceFrom(double x2, double y2) {
        double x3 = x2 - this.x;
        double y3 = y2 - this.y; 
        double sqaureadd = (y3 * y3) + (x3 * x3);
        double distance = Math.sqrt(sqaureadd);
        return distance;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Read more about "constructor" in terms of JAVA classes, you will be able to figure out. For now you can change the names of the methods `newPointParameters` and `newPoint ` to `Point`. Remove `void` from the method signature and add `Point p = new Point(42, 24)` in `main` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, currently, neither newPointParameters nor newPoint are constructors. Rather, they are just methods. To make them into constructors, they need to share the same name as the class the construct

```
class Point {

  private double x = 1;
  private double y = 1;

  public Point() {
    this.x = 10;
    this.y = 10;
  }

  public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
```

Then, when you want to create a new point, you simply do the following

For a default point

```
public class Lab4ex1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("" + 100);

    //this will create a new Point object, and call the Point() constructor
    Point point = new Point();
}
```

For the Point with parameters

```
public class Lab4ex1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("" + 100);

    //this will create a new Point object, and call the 
    //Point(double x, double y) constructor
    Point point = new Point(10.0, 10.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("" + 100);
    Point p = new Point();
    p.newPointParameter(42,24);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`newPointParameters` is not a constructor. I think this is what you are looking to do:

```
public Point(double x1, double y1) {
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
}
```

Then you can create a `Point` object in your main class using this constructor:

```
Point p = new Point(42, 24);
```

It looks like you also intended for `newPoint()` to be a constructor, so it should look like this:

```
public Point() {
    x = 10;
    y = 10;
}
```